# Count except zeros

Tags: postgresql

How can I count a number of record where zeros are not counted?

```
SELECT c.id AS Id
        ,c.A AS A
        ,sum(phtd.RealCol1) / 3600 AS RealCol1
        ,CAST(count(phtd.RealCol1) AS DECIMAL) AS RealCol2
    FROM ubdr
    INNER JOIN cfg c ON (ubdr.B = c.id)
    INNER JOIN per_historico phtd ON (
            phtd.B = ubdr.B
            AND ubdr.D = phtd.D
            )
    INNER JOIN per_t pt ON (phtd.T= pt.id)
    INNER JOIN per_p pa ON (pa.T= pt.id)
    WHERE 1 = 1
    GROUP BY 1
        ,2
```

I wrote this `CAST(count(phtd.RealCol1) AS DECIMAL) AS RealCol2`, but this count is counting zeros as well. How can I achieve counting records without counting zeros? I mean counting records distinct of zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=85329c077ad5df37a79ca6ffe1a48e48)

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
COUNT(phtd.RealCol1) FILTER (WHERE phtd.RealCol1 <> 0)
```

Instead of using `FILTER` clause you can use a conditional `SUM` using the `CASE` clause:

```
SUM(
   CASE WHEN phtd.RealCol1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
)
```

This can be optimized to:

```
SUM((phtd.RealCol1 <> 0)::int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `CAST(count(phtd.RealCol1) AS DECIMAL) AS RealCol2`, you can use `SUM`:

`CAST(SUM( CASE WHEN phtd.RealCol1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS DECIMAL) AS RealCol2`

or, you can use `FILTER`:

`CAST((COUNT(phtd.RealCol1) FILTER (WHERE phtd.RealCol1 > 0)) AS DECIMAL) AS RealCol2`